# How to Query Wikidata for US persidents?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How to Query Wikidata for US presidents, who started their presidency after 1970 AND have at least one daughter?

I know how to query for US presidents but I don't know how to filter my search.

```
SELECT ?presLabel ?spouseLabel ?picp ?picps ?daughterLabel ?numchild ?start WHERE {

   ?pres wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
   ?pres p:P39 ?position_held_statement .
   ?position_held_statement ps:P39 wd:Q11696 .
   ?position_held_statement pq:P580 ?start .


   ?pres wdt:P26 ?spouse .
   ?pres wdt:P40 ?childern.
   ?pres wdt:P40 ?daughter.
   ?daughter wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072.
   ?pres wdt:P1971 ?numchild.

   OPTIONAL {
        ?pres wdt:P18 ?picp
    } 

   OPTIONAL {
        ?spouse wdt:P18 ?picps
    } 

   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }

 } ORDER BY ?start
```

Comment: all eight of them have daughters

Comment: @arkanciscan I need the query, not the answer. But thanks.

Comment: It would be good if you show your current query such that we can start with this.

Comment: @AKSW I added my query to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that difficult:

1. You already have the start time which is of type `xsd:date`. All you have to do now is to extract the year and use this value for filtering:

   `FILTER(year(?start) > 1970)`
2. Your second condition "at least one daughter" is implicitly satisfied by the join, i.e. the presidents only match if there is such data. It would become more "interesting" if you're asking for "at least two daughters" because then you would have to group by each president, count the daughters and finally filter the groups:

   ```
   GROUP BY ?p 
   HAVING (count(?child) > 2)
   ```

Your final query:

```sql
SELECT ?presLabel ?spouseLabel ?picp ?picps ?daughterLabel ?numchild ?start WHERE {

   ?pres wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
   ?pres p:P39 ?position_held_statement .
   ?position_held_statement ps:P39 wd:Q11696 .
   ?position_held_statement pq:P580 ?start .

   # the spouse
   ?pres wdt:P26 ?spouse .
   # all daughters
   ?pres wdt:P40 ?daughter.
   ?daughter wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072.
   # number of children
   ?pres wdt:P1971 ?numchild.

   OPTIONAL {
        ?pres wdt:P18 ?picp
    } 

   OPTIONAL {
        ?spouse wdt:P18 ?picps
    } 

  # filter by start date here
  FILTER(year(?start) > 1970)

   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }

 } ORDER BY ?start
```

#### Additional Task

The number of daughters can be retrieved in a subquery which simply has to be put inside the original query + adding the variable `?numDaughters` to the selected variables:

```
# here we compute the number of daughters 
{ 
 select ?pres (count(distinct ?daughter) as ?numDaughters) where {
        ?pres wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
        ?pres p:P39 ?position_held_statement .
        ?position_held_statement ps:P39 wd:Q11696 .
        # all daughters
        ?pres wdt:P40 ?daughter.
        ?daughter wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072.
 } 
 group by ?pres
}
```

Comment: Firstly Thank you.  And could I ask you, how could I implement the ```GROUP BY ?p 
HAVING (count(?child) > 2)``` that you mentioned like condition without adding a query in ```Select``` ?

Comment: I tried this ```(COUNT(?daughter) AS ?numD)``` to ```Select``` and ```Group By ?pres``` at the end of ```Select``` and then filter it but I get ```Query is malformed: Bad aggregate``` error.

Comment: Well, indeed if you use grouping, all other selected non-grouping variables have also to be processed by some aggregate function. this is natural because you create a group which finally will represent just one row. If you still want to have separate rows for e.g. each spouse, you need to compute that value in a sub-SELECT.

Comment: @DSaad I added an example to my answer.